# passing multiple functions inside main function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve a workaround which calls two functions inside a main function on the basis of if condition. The main function is toggled onClick/onChange event handler.

```
fetchData = command => e => {
    if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      console.log("Button Clicked!");

      this.setState({
        command
      });

      this.ButtonData = command => {
        console.log(command, "command received");
      };
    } else if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
      console.log("Input Clicked!");

      this.setState({
        command
      });

      this.InputData = command => {
        console.log(command, "command received");
      };
    }
  };
```

The code only works till first console printing, 'clicked' but then doesn't follow inside the function called in if condition.

Here is the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-bash-fmmmd

Please help to achieve the same.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the endresult you want to achieve? I just tried the sandbox and when I click on the button it prints "Button clicked" and when typing in the Input Field it prints "Input Clicked". So it should also work when I click into the input field?

Comment: Don't quite understand what is that you want to achieve

Comment: @Gh05d It is only printing the console of parent function fetchData(), that is initiated onClick/onChange of button and input element. After detecting the tagName, for e.g., BUTTON, it should then execute function ButtonData()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way, try to paste it in your example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      command: "",
      text_start: "enter text one",
      text_end: "enter text two"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  buttonData = command => {
  console.log(command, "command received");
  };

  inputData = command => {
    console.log(command, "command received");
  };

  fetchData = command => e => {
    if (e.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      console.log("Button Clicked!");

      this.setState({
        command
      });

      this.buttonData(command);
    } else if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
      console.log("Input Clicked!");

      this.setState({
        command
      });

      this.inputData(command);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <button value="start" onClick={this.fetchData("start")}>
            Start
          </button>
          <button value="stop" onClick={this.fetchData("stop")}>
            Stop
          </button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="start"
            value={this.state.text_start}
            onChange={this.fetchData("e")}
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            name="end"
            value={this.state.text_end}
            onChange={this.fetchData("e")}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was trying to achieve :) But one thing that it does not seem changing the value of the input box

Comment: What do you expect to change ? Anyway you have to add a _value_ attribute to the input if you want to fill it with data